# transfer programs like Office 2010 that is on a Windows 7 PC to a new PC with Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-easy-transfer

How do you transfer programs like Office 2010 that is on a Windows 7 PC to a new PC with Windows 10? I want to keep all the settings and Outlook folders from the old PC. I can not find the "Easy Transfer" program on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the program installation (including license key, etc.) or just the files and settings?

Comment: I would like to transfer the program installation and files and settings.  I have the orig Office 2010 disc with license key.  I did not want to start from scratch with the settings and I have all kinds of Outlook folders ad subfolders with emails that I need to keep.  I thought I could use " MS Easy Transfer"  program but, windows 10 does not support it to my best try.

Comment: try the free **PCmover Express**: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/transfer-your-data

Answer (score 0):

If you want transfer your stuff to a new PC, there's bad news: Windows 10 no longer includes its Easy Transfer software that lets you automatically move files and settings between two PCs.

So you have to do everything manually. You can transfer files, programs and settings by [EaseUS Todo PCTrans](http://www.easeus.com/free-pc-transfer-software/), the pay edition will need about $50, that will let you transfer everything between two computers on the same network, may be more powerful, you can also download a free trial that lets you transfer two applications.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Easy Transfer is indeed gone from Windows 10, but actually it would not help you anyway: it could only transfer files, not the actual Office 2010 installation.

The only way to do such a transfer is to use a 3rd party tool. There are several out there, the ones I've heard of are Zinstall, EaseUS and PCMover. I've tried all three in the past few years, the one that really worked for me was Zinstall.

Here is their tutorial with video that shows how to do the entire process:
[How to transfer programs to new PC](http://www.zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-programs-and-files-to-new-computer)